# dropdown hover display div or modal at same position for all dropdowns

Tags: c#, css

hi all i am trying to use the dropdown in navigation bar and want  a div to be displayed on hover on all of   the dropdown what should i do. i tried but i want that div should  be displayed at the same position for all the dropdown. I tried with modal of bootstrap but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

your question are not giving enough information to some one to help.
any ways, i highly recommend if you want a dropdown menu, read [the bootstrap starting guide](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)